# Как удалить бордер элемента бутсрап который появляется после нажатия на нее

Tags: bootstrap

[image: Вот так выглядит раздражающий бордер после нажатия]

Я пытался убрать бордеры в css как показано ниже

```css
.btn:after{
  border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```css
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none!important;
    border-color: #000!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="p-3">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил. Получается это был не `border` а `box-shadow`

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, это у тебя `input`, а не `button`

```
.form-control:focus{
  border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Проблема не исчезла, бордер все еще присутствует после нажатия